# Why -th and -eth are followed after verbs?

Tags: grammar, verbs, early-modern-english

What does called that form added `-th or -eth` after verbs.I found that in an article and don't know why it was used ? Is it specialized verbs ? In which condition ,should I use that!

> And he that **taketh** not his cross, and **followeth** after me, is not worthy of me.

[Article Link](https://www.bible.com/users/davidjawphan/reading-plans/2917-ben-hur/ref?content=0&day=1&id=2917-ben-hur)

Answer (score 2):

The  ending *-eth* is not used anymore, outside of very old texts (or versions thereof)  that are still read today, such as The King James Version (KJV)  of the Holy Bible.

Modern translations usually  use modern English, as in  the *English Standard Verizon* (2001):

> And whoever does not take his cross and follow me is not worthy of me.

([See, for example](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2010:37-39&version=ESV))

So the short answer is *don't use it*, unless you want to sound like early modern English (ca AD/CE 1600).